# How can I set a method to point to anything in my unit test using MagicMock?

Tags: python, mocking

I have the following class, function and unit test, but I am running into an error when I try to mock out a certain method. Any ideas how to achieve what I desire below?

```
 class Index:

    def __init__(
        self,
        issuer: str,
        code: str,
        opening_closing: str,
        db_session: DatabaseSession,
        constants: Optional[MetadataConstants] = None,
    ):

        def some_function(self):

            ...

            has_constituents = self._db_session.execute(
        SQL.FETCH_INDEX_HAS_CONSTITUENTS, params_dict).fetchall()
 
            does_index_have_constituents = strtobool(has_constituents[0][0])

            return does_index_have_constituents



@pytest.fixture
def index(mock_metadata_constants):
    db_session_mock = mock.MagicMock()
    db_session_mock.execute = True
    index = Index(
        issuer="something",
        code="something",
        opening_closing="O",
        db_session=db_session_mock,
        constants=mock_metadata_constants,
    )
    return index
```

When I run the above, I get:

```
    some_function = self._db_session.execute(
>           SQL.FETCH_INDEX_HAS_CONSTITUENTS, params_dict).fetchall()
E       TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

And I totally understand why I am getting the error.

But I'm not sure how to mock out `has_constituents` points to `True` or whatever.